# Cordova Spellchecking

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to implement spell checking in to my cordova porject. I know that webview android does not support

```
<div id="textarea" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">
```

is there an alternative to the webview which does support this HTML or do I need to use the spell checker frame work?

Comment: Does [crosswalk plugin](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html) [support spellcheck](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/chromium-crosswalk/blob/master/chrome/renderer/spellchecker/spellcheck.h)?

Comment: That is my question... does crosswalk or qt webview ect, support spellcheck on android?

Comment: It might be faster for you just to try this rather than wait for an answer :)

Comment: Think I will try it, why has no one just made a table of android webviews and the HTML they can support

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! Would be a great addition to http://caniuse.com/

Comment: Crosswalk does not work with html spell check, just to let you know

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, Android WebView has supported the `spellcheck` attribute since v47: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck#browser_compatibility

With cordova-android 10.1.2 I *can* get this to work in the Android emulator with WebView v91 and Android 12.

*But* I have been unsuccessful in getting this to work with WebView v119 on an Android 13 device. You'll also notice that in the Android Chrome app v119 that there are no settings for Spellcheck like there is in the Windows version of Chrome.

I suspect that somewhere between WebView v91 and 119 they lost the capability to do spellchecking.